# Determine Document Set sub folders in ItemAdded Remote Event Receiver

Tags: sharepoint-online, remote-event-receiver

I am building an `ItemAdded` Remote Event Receiver that is attached to a Document Library which contains a content type derived from the **Document Set**.

The **Document Sets** are configured to deploy sub-folders. Now when those sub folders are deployed SharePoint automatically also assigns the content type of the sub-folders as the derived **Document Set**.  It would be nice if the sub folder's content type were just "Folder" but sadly they are not. So my goal is to reassign the content type of the sub-folder and do some other security manipulations. There is my problem.

In the processing of the `ItemAdded` event I need to examine the item being added so I determine if the item is the Document Set itself, a Document Set sub-folder or something else. Now since SharePoint assigns the sub-folder's content type the same as the parent a **Document Set** I am not able to compare content types to determine if it is a sub folder. I am also unable to use the `FileSystemObjectType` property because both the sub-folder and the parent content type are being returned as Folders. This leaves me unable to figure out how to isolate just the sub-folders. Below is my code. Hopefully someone has a better idea than what my approach is so far.

Thanks for reading!

```
public void ProcessOneWayEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
{
    using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
    {
        clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
        clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web.Lists);
        clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web.ContentTypes);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        List parentList = clientContext.Web.Lists.SingleOrDefault(l => l.Id == properties.ItemEventProperties.ListId);
        ListItem item = parentList.GetItemById(properties.ItemEventProperties.ListItemId);
        ContentType engineeringDocSetCT = clientContext.Web.ContentTypes.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == "Engineering Project");

        clientContext.Load(item);
        clientContext.Load(item.Folder);
        clientContext.Load(item.ContentType);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        switch (item.ContentType.Name)
        {
            case "Engineering Project":

                // This test does not work. Sub-folders and the Engineering Projct
                // Item come back as Folders
                if (item.FileSystemObjectType == FileSystemObjectType.Folder)
                {
                    Folder itemFolder = item.Folder;
                    string folderName = itemFolder.Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    string _projectName = properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["Title"].ToString();
                    string _projNum = properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["Project_x0020_Number"].ToString();
                    string _projRegion = properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["Project_x0020_Region"].ToString();
                    string _projSite = properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["Project_x0020_Site"].ToString();

                    item["Enginering_x0020_Project_x0020_Name"] = _projectName;
                    item["Project_x0020_Number"] = "New Project #";
                    item.Update();

                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                }

                break;

            default:
                break;

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: FYI: The `FileSystemObjectType` evaluates as a folder because a Document Set *is* a folder. It's an inherited content type from the base folder content type with additional features.

Comment: Yes apparently so.